# How to delete some specify row from a table

Tags: mysql

I have a test table

```
mysql> select * from test1 limit 20;
+------+------+----------------------------------+
| id   | num  | pass                             |
+------+------+----------------------------------+
|    1 |    1 | c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b |
|    2 |    3 | c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c |
|    1 |    1 | c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b |
|    2 |    2 | c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c |
|    1 |    1 | c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b |
|    2 |    3 | c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c |
|    3 |    3 | eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3 |
|    4 |    6 | a87ff679a2f3e71d9181a67b7542122c |
|    5 |    7 | e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5 |
|    6 |    6 | 1679091c5a880faf6fb5e6087eb1b2dc |
|    7 |    8 | 8f14e45fceea167a5a36dedd4bea2543 |
|    8 |   11 | c9f0f895fb98ab9159f51fd0297e236d |
|    9 |   10 | 45c48cce2e2d7fbdea1afc51c7c6ad26 |
|   10 |   12 | d3d9446802a44259755d38e6d163e820 |
|   11 |   12 | 6512bd43d9caa6e02c990b0a82652dca |
|   12 |   18 | c20ad4d76fe97759aa27a0c99bff6710 |
...
```

I want to delete the 1st,3rd and 9th row.So I use such command

```
delete from test1 limit 1,3,9;
```

But it doesn't work,is there any workaround can do this?

Comment: why you need  the 1,3, 9  .. this have a logic?

Comment: The apparent lack of a PRIMARY KEY is likely to prove problematic

Comment: First, third, and ninth rows with regard to _which_ ordering?

Comment: @scaisEdge Sorry,no logic,I'm just try to learning *mysql*

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen As its inward order.Can it be implement?

Comment: then mysql don't work .. this way .. For SQL operations you need to identify a set of valid values in your case limit use is not allowed to filter rows from a list

Comment: @scaisEdge Anyway,thanks a lot. :)

Comment: If you know which records you want to delete, just record their data and code a delete statement.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry,I don't now what meaning of your `records`..